# Use of "introductory" in titles

Tags: meaning, expressions, semantics

Consider the following titles for, say, a name of a university course, or a textbook:

- "Introduction to McGuffin Systems"
- "Introductory McGuffin Systems"
- "McGuffin Systems Introductory"

and let's suppose the course does actually teach you about McGuffin Systems (i.e. not like the introduction to a book where the actual contents comes afterwards).

Which of these three titles is (more) valid for use? Which - to the best of your knowledge - is more commonly used? And does any of them carry a nuance of meaning which the others do not?

Comment: The first one sounds more logical to me.

Comment: The last one is wrong in any context. The first two convey slightly different meanings - Introduction to McGuffin Systems introduces the reader to McGuffin Systems, but it may include both basic and advanced content, whereas Introductory McGuffin Systems implies it only contains basic, introductory content. The first one makes more sense as a title, but both #1 and #2 seem fine.

Comment: Is this BE or AE??

Answer (score 0):

The answer may depend on whether McGuffin Systems **themselves** exist in different versions, such as introductory, intermediate, advanced, or it is just that the university courses about them are taught at different levels. If it's the latter, then there is really no such thing as introductory McGuffin Systems. That entails that one should avoid using *Introductory McGuffin Systems* as a title for a course. The title that would correctly reflect what the course is would be *Introduction to McGuffin Systems*.

If there were such a thing as introductory McGuffin Systems, one could, of course, name a university course about them *Introductory McGuffin Systems*, but that would not, strictly speaking, mean that the course itself is at the introductory level: it is logically possible to study introductory McGuffin Systems at an advanced level. (Or, to use a more realistic example, there can be advanced courses on how to teach introductory-level English.)

Notwithstanding the above argument, one does sometimes see titles such as *Introductory Astronomy* or *Introductory Biology*. These seem to be cases of a **transferred epithet**: the modifier *introductory* is transferred from the noun that it, by its meaning, qualifies, *course*, to another noun, so as to produce a more compact, easier to handle, formulation. *Introductory Course in Astronomy* thus becomes *Introductory Astronomy*.

Now, if using *introductory* as a transferred epithet is accepted when it comes to astronomy and biology, could we, in spite of the above argument against it, use *Introductory McGuffin Systems* to mean an introductory course on McGuffin Systems? We could, but it seems unwise to do that. When it is used as a transferred epithet, *introductory* is typically followed by a name of some established academic discipline, such as astronomy or biology. Using it in the same way with a term for something that is not an established academic discipline, like *McGuffin Systems*, would be pushing the boundaries of what is acceptable. In some cases, pushing the boundaries of what is acceptable may be a good thing, but it is not clear what would be the benefit of doing so in this case, given that a much safer, entirely unproblematic alternative, *Introduction to McGuffin Systems* is readily available.

It is difficult to imagine a context in which putting *introductory* after *McGuffin Systems* would be a good idea. The closest thing to this that might sometimes be appropriate would be to put *introductory* in a subtitle, as in *McGuffin Systems: An Introductory Textbook*.